# Can a company change a policy and enforce it like this?

Tags: contracts, company-policy, legal, education

If an organization offers an online education policy as a perquisite (after being employed for a certain period) and the policy states that it's free for the employees if they opt-in and they'll have to pay 50% of the fee if they decide to leave the organization before completion of the course.

So if an employee opts-in to this policy, and after a while decides to leave the organization, can the organization change the policy right before that claiming that someone leaving (before completion of the course) will have to pay the complete amount (instead of the 50%).

Is this legal? If not, what are the possible ways to raise this without jeopardizing the whole thing and without it seeming like a legal threat?

**Perquisite**: *a benefit (in lieu of salary) which one enjoys or is entitled to on account of one's job or position, which is taxable*

Comment: This is likely off topic here, as you are asking about their own policy and legal advice around it. You will need to ask either the company whether that is legal, or a lawyer. The answer will entirely depend on country/state/contract.

Comment: I want advice on basic contract conditions, can organization change a policy already agreed upon and enforce the new policy without having an option to opt-out of it? To me this looks like a scam because then no policy would mean anything as it can be changed at will

Comment: That's what a lawyer can answer. Maybe folk at /law would be willing to take a crack at it too, in the generalized form.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)

Comment: A policy is generally something an organisation can change at will. A contract between two parties cannot simply be changed by one party. You would probably have to have signed a document to receive this benefit. Your should go over the wording of that document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So if an employee opts-in to this policy, and after a while decides to leave the
> organization, can the organization change the policy right before that claiming that
> someone leaving (before completion of the course) will have to pay the
> complete amount (instead of the 50%).

They can. You only have the rights that you are willing to fight for in court.

Here is what I would argue in court: The policy relevant for a specific course if the policy that was in force at the moment I legally signed up for the course, because the repayment policy is part of my (as employee) decision process and a later change is not something I should have to bear.

TONS of similar references. Contract as is in force at the time of incident, not later changes. See, i.e., the recent Patreon decision (not employment, but they tried something like this).

You seriously would need legal advice. From a lawyer. Because, obviously, I am non, do not know your jurisdiction (how comes people ask legal questions without tagging by at least country?) and all the details that may matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have omitted the country to keep it anonymous, my apologies for that. I just wanted to get a general idea if this is remotely possible or is it absolutely illegal. 

Thanks for your help, I'll consider legal advice for more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a company change a policy and enforce it like this?

Sure they can. They just did.

> Is this legal?

This depends HIGHLY on your local jurisdiction and how exactly the policy and the change are worded. Only a local expert can answer that.

> If not, what are the possible ways to raise this without jeopardizing the whole thing and without it seeming like a legal threat?

Regardless of whether it's legal or not, you can always ask nicely. "Hi, I see that you changed a policy so it's a little less favorable for the employees. Since the policy was different when I signed my contract: does the old or the new version apply to me ? "